# Looping through nesting of objects and arrays with Javascript and underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I am trying to access objects that are nested within an array.  I start with this JSON object (which was derived from an XML database output):

```
{"report":
        {"date":"15 Apr 2016",
         "metrics":
            {"metric":
               [
                {"name":"Bank Angle",
                 "display_parent_group":"Bankfull",
                 "display_child_group":"SiteShape",
                 "tolerance":"0.05",
                 "visits":
                  {"visit":
                   [
                    {"visit_id":"3047","value": "0.47"},
                    {"visit_id":"2164","value": "0.55"},
                    {"visit_id":"1568","value": "0.72"},
                    {"visit_id":"3431","value": "0.12"},
                    {"visit_id":"2428","value": "0.44"},
                    {"visit_id":"1567","value": "0.49"}
                   ]}},
                {"name":"Bank Angle SD",
                 "display_parent_group":"Bankfull",
                 "display_child_group":"SiteShape",
                 "tolerance":"0.05",
                 "visits":
                 {"visit":
                  [
                   {"visit_id":"3047","value": "0.12"},
                   {"visit_id":"2164","value": "0.05"},
                   {"visit_id":"1568","value": "0.21"},
                   {"visit_id":"3431","value": "0.68"},
                   {"visit_id":"2428","value": "0.22"},
                   {"visit_id":"1567","value": "0.13"}
                  ]}},
               {"name":"Bankfull Area",
                "display_parent_group":"Bankfull",
                "display_child_group":"SiteSize","tolerance":"0.05",
                "visits":
                 {"visit":
                  [
                   {"visit_id":"3047","value": "202"},
                   {"visit_id":"2164","value": "193"},
                   {"visit_id":"1568","value": "115"},
                   {"visit_id":"3431","value": "258"},
                   {"visit_id":"2428","value": "89"},
                   {"visit_id":"1567","value": "206"}
                  ]}}
               ]
             }
          }
}
```

I then use underscore to extract a subset of `metric` objects:

```
var table_metric = JSONData.report.metrics.metric;

var target_metrics = _.where(table_metric, {
                  display_parent_group : 'Bankfull', display_child_group: 'SiteShape'
                  });
```

This results in an array with two nested objects. Where I'm having a problem is then accessing the array of objects which is nested inside `visits.visit`. If, for instance, I want to build an array of values associated with the key `visit_id`, and I try:

```
function buildVisitIDArray(target_metrics) {
    var attrList = [];
    for(var i=0; i<target_metrics.length; i++) {
      var visit_records = target_metrics[i].visits[1];
      console.log(visit_records);
      for(visit_record in visit_records) {
        attrList.push(_.pluck(visit_record, "visit_id"));
    } 
}
return attrList
```

}

I just get an array of undefined results.  I've spent hours trying variations on the syntax to get at the nested "visit" objects, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated for this novice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your buildVisitIDArray function, you are trying to get target_metrics[i].visits[1] as if it was an array, but it's actually an object, so you should use it this way:

```
function buildVisitIDArray(target_metrics) {
    attrList = [];
    for(var i=0; i<target_metrics.length; i++) {
        var visit_records = target_metrics[i].visits; // Removed the array call ([1])
        console.log(visit_records);
        for(visit_record in visit_records) {
            attrList.push(_.pluck(visit_records[visit_record], "visit_id"));
        }
    }
    return attrList;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks André.  Now I get an array with the correct length (5), but all of the items are 'undefined'.  I'm still not doing something right.

Comment: @tinyplanet00 my mistake. I didn't saw the return of the function. Fixed it. In your for(visit_record in visit_records), the visit_record is a key, not a value. So, you must access using visit_records[visit_record]. Now it's returning a bunch of IDs :) (the code is edited in my solution)

Comment: You're welcome! Would you mind to upvote my solution, please, @tinyplanet00?

Answer (score 0):

You may also have an issue if you're not defining `attrList` with the `var` keyword somewhere else in your code.

Building on Andre's answer, you may want to change this line to be:

`visit_records = target_metrics[i].visits.visit;`

to go one layer deeper, then do a regular array `for` loop afterward.

Comment: Oops. Yes you're right.  Edited my question. Thanks!